# Meteor JS - mizzao:timesync package. How to set up a little counter

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Hi guys, i will need a bit of help for all of those who use Meteor.js / or simply NodeJS**

I notice there is a package on meteor called: mizzaO.timesync: https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/timesync

I have in mind to do a little counter, from the server to the client.

Server should send a timestamp, or 60 seconds to the client. And client should get every second.

Im sure i will need to use moment.js too.

How can i aprroach this situation? So, server will send 60 seconds to the client, and client will update ever 1 second, to get the server time.

Thanks!.

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to achieve here? You question is a little vague

Comment: Well, i dont think is vague, im just a bit newby as i sayd. So i cant explain myself in the correct way. I edited the post. Thanks for ur reply..

Comment: So you want the client to update the time displayed on screen every second and sync with the server every 60 seconds to make sure the time is right?

Comment: If so, the simplest way is just to use a `setInterval` function to update the DOM every second and use the built in interval from `mizzao:timesync` to get the server time

Comment: Are you using Blaze for templates?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the help. Im using react JS, i need to get every second  from the server and display it into the client yeah! Or a date.now() and display it into the client, and update the client like x times, to notice if date is right.. something like that. But a timmer would be better, getting every second from the server to the client. Thanks for the replys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain HTML / JS you would need:

A DOM element to display the time

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

And some JS:

```
let currentTime = new Date();

Tracker.autorun( () => {
    // This will run automatically every time the serverTime updates. ie. every 60 seconds
    TimeSync.serverTime(null, 60000);
    currentTime = new Date( Date.now() + TimeSync.serverOffset() );
});

setInterval( () => {
    // This calculates the approximate server time and updates the DOM every second
    currentTime = new Date( Date.now() + TimeSync.serverOffset() );
    document.getElementById('time').innerText = currentTime.toLocaleDateString();
}, 1000);
```

Answer obviously not using react, but you should be able to figure that part out

Comment: Hey Frederick thanks a lot for ur fast and good reply. Have a good day, and thanks you! :*